# Impossible to reach HomeController routes with enabled UseAuthentication

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

As title says, I want to  implement some kind of authorization in .NET Core 2.1, but I have a trouble following their tutorials. I have set up the Startup.cs file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        if (_currentEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            services.AddDbContext<PagesContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection), ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
        else
            services.AddDbContext<PagesContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connection), ServiceLifetime.Singleton);

        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(opts=>
        {
            opts.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            opts.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            opts.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            opts.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            opts.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = null;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<PagesContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddSingleton<IStringLocalizerFactory, EFStringLocalizerFactory>();
        services.AddMvc();

    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseStatusCodePages();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
            new CultureInfo("en"),
            new CultureInfo("ru-RU"),
            new CultureInfo("ru"),
            new CultureInfo("uk-UA"),
            new CultureInfo("ua")
        };
        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("ru-RU"),
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        });
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(
            routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            }
        );
```

And I have the HomeController.cs file with following contents:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {

        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Admin"))
            {
                return LocalRedirectPermanent("/Admin/Index");
            }
            else if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Carrier"))
            {
                return LocalRedirectPermanent("/Carrier/Index");
            }
            return LocalRedirectPermanent("/Passenger/Index");
        }
        Page indexPage = db.Page.Include(u => u.Title).Include(u => u.Description).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Tag == "main_page");
        return View();
    }
```

As it can be seen from the code I want to detect, if user is logged in - to show the corresponding page. If not - page, which enables login procedure. But the default route is ignored, when authentication is used. If I launch this from Visual Studio, it navigates me to /Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2FPassenger%2FIndex , not /Home/Index. How can I override this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. And it seems, it it not the fault of .NET Core. It based on headers.
In my case, `LocalRedirectPermanent("/Admin/Index")` was called several times, therefore, it automatically called "/Admin/Index", bypassing "/Home/Index". I think, it is due to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301). Therefore, I have fixed in my browser(Firefox) this way: Reset the history(forms, cookies, etc) and perform in Visual Studio Build->Rebuild Solution. And it started working again. Hope, this helped someone